# Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm in python not working

Tags: python, algorithm, directed-graph, tarjans-algorithm

I implemented the Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm, according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_pseudocode), in Python, but it isn't working. The algorithm is quite short and I cannot find any difference, so I cannot tell why it isn't working. I tried to check the original paper, but could not find it.

Here is the code.

```
def strongConnect(v):
  global E, idx, CCs, c, S
  idx[v] = (c, c) #idx[v][0] for v.index # idx[v][1] for v.lowlink
  c += 1
  S.append(v)  
  for w in [u for (v2, u) in E if v == v2]:
    if idx[w][0] < 0:
      strongConnect(w)
      # idx[w] = (idx[w][0], min(idx[v][1], idx[w][1])) #fixed, thx
      idx[v] = (idx[v][0], min(idx[v][1], idx[w][1]))
    elif w in S:
      idx[v] = (idx[v][0], min(idx[v][1], idx[w][0]))
  if (idx[v][0] == idx[v][1]):
    i = S.index(v)
    CCs.append(S[i:])
    S = S[:i]

E = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'A'), ('A', 'E'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'E'), ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'B'), ('E', 'F')]
idx = {}
CCs = []
c = 0
S = []
for (u, v) in E:
  idx[u] = (-1, -1)
  idx[v] = (-1, -1)
for v in idx.keys():
  if idx[v][0] < 0:
    strongConnect(v)

print(CCs)
```

You can [check the graph visually](http://desmond.imageshack.us/Himg687/scaled.php?server=687&filename=exampleu.png&res=medium) if you prefer. As you can see this is a quite forward translation of the pseudocode in wikipedia. However, this is the output:

```
[['D', 'E', 'F'], ['B', 'C'], ['A']]
```

There should be only one strongly connected component, not three. I hope the question is right in all its aspects, if not I'm sorry. In any case, thank you very much.

Comment: Algorithmic descriptions and Python are a collision of unreadable and readable which makes me not want to parse this. Here is Tarjan[1972] implemented more readably: http://www.bitformation.com/art/python_toposort.html

Comment: And another: http://www.logarithmic.net/pfh-files/blog/01208083168/sort.py

Comment: that works, msw, thank you, I'll check that, my implementation and wikipedia and try to fix it. Thank you.

Comment: You might also want to check out the implementation (a slight variation of Tarjan) in `networkx` which is a really nice python graph analysis package: http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/generated/networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected.strongly_connected_components.html#networkx.algorithms.components.strongly_connected.strongly_connected_components

Comment: This is just a prototype, I have to modify this algorithm to suit my needs in Java, along with [an algorithm to find strong articulation points](http://www.springerlink.com/content/gt07037641261750/) and one to [calculate dominator tree](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/249720/efficient-way-to-recursively-calculate-dominator-tree) as soon as I find it. But the library is cool, so I'll keep it for future reference, thank you.

Comment: The image in your original post is out of date: it no longer renders anything resembling an image

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Ok, I had some more time to think about this. I'm no longer certain that filtering the edges was the problem, as I previously stated. In fact, I think there's an ambiguity in the [pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm#The_algorithm_in_pseudocode); does `for each (v, w) in  E` mean for *each edge* (as the literal meaning of `for each` suggests), or only each edge beginning with `v`, (as you reasonably assumed)? Then, after the for loop, is the `v` in question the final `v` from the `for` loop, as it would be in Python? Or does that go back to being the original `v`? Pseudocode doesn't have clearly defined scoping behavior in this case! (It would be really weird if the `v` at the end were to be the last, arbitrary, value of `v` from the loop. That suggests that filtering is correct, because in that case, `v` means the same thing all the way through.)

However, under any circumstances, the *clear* error in your code is here:

```
  idx[w] = (idx[w][0], min(idx[v][1], idx[w][1]))
```

According to the pseudocode, that should definitely be

```
  idx[v] = (idx[v][0], min(idx[v][1], idx[w][1]))
```

Once you make that change, you get the expected result. Frankly it doesn't surprise me that you made that mistake, because you're using a really weird and counterintuitive data structure. Here's what I think is an improvement -- it adds only a few more lines, and I find it to be much more readable.

```
import itertools

def strong_connect(vertex):
    global edges, indices, lowlinks, connected_components, index, stack
    indices[vertex] = index
    lowlinks[vertex] = index
    index += 1
    stack.append(vertex)

    for v, w in (e for e in edges if e[0] == vertex):
        if indices[w] < 0:
            strong_connect(w)
            lowlinks[v] = min(lowlinks[v], lowlinks[w])
        elif w in stack:
            lowlinks[v] = min(lowlinks[v], indices[w])

    if indices[vertex] == lowlinks[vertex]:
        connected_components.append([])
        while stack[-1] != vertex:
            connected_components[-1].append(stack.pop())
        connected_components[-1].append(stack.pop())

edges = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), 
         ('E', 'A'), ('A', 'E'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'E'), 
         ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'B'), ('E', 'F')]
vertices = set(v for v in itertools.chain(*edges))
indices = dict((v, -1) for v in vertices)
lowlinks = indices.copy()
connected_components = []

index = 0
stack = []
for v in vertices:
    if indices[v] < 0:
        strong_connect(v)

print(connected_components)
```

However, I find the use of global variables here distasteful. You could hide this away in its own module, but I prefer the idea of creating a callable class. After looking more closely at Tarjan's [original pseudocode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Tarjan%27s_strongly_connected_components_algorithm#Status_of_the_algorithm), (which confirms that the "filtered" version is correct, by the way), I wrote this. It includes a simple `Graph` class and does couple of basic tests:

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict

class Graph(object):
    def __init__(self, edges, vertices=()):
        edges = list(list(x) for x in edges)
        self.edges = edges
        self.vertices = set(chain(*edges)).union(vertices)
        self.tails = defaultdict(list)
        for head, tail in self.edges:
            self.tails[head].append(tail)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, edge_dict):
        return cls((k, v) for k, vs in edge_dict.iteritems() for v in vs)

class _StrongCC(object):
    def strong_connect(self, head):
        lowlink, count, stack = self.lowlink, self.count, self.stack
        lowlink[head] = count[head] = self.counter = self.counter + 1
        stack.append(head)

        for tail in self.graph.tails[head]:
            if tail not in count:
                self.strong_connect(tail)
                lowlink[head] = min(lowlink[head], lowlink[tail])
            elif count[tail] < count[head]:
                if tail in self.stack:
                    lowlink[head] = min(lowlink[head], count[tail])

        if lowlink[head] == count[head]:
            component = []
            while stack and count[stack[-1]] >= count[head]:
                component.append(stack.pop())
            self.connected_components.append(component)

    def __call__(self, graph):
        self.graph = graph
        self.counter = 0
        self.count = dict()
        self.lowlink = dict()
        self.stack = []
        self.connected_components = []

        for v in self.graph.vertices:
            if v not in self.count:
                self.strong_connect(v)

        return self.connected_components

strongly_connected_components = _StrongCC()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    edges = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'),
             ('E', 'A'), ('A', 'E'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'E'),
             ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'B'), ('E', 'F')]
    print strongly_connected_components(Graph(edges))
    edge_dict = {'a':['b', 'c', 'd'],
                 'b':['c', 'a'],
                 'c':['d', 'e'],
                 'd':['e'],
                 'e':['c']}
    print strongly_connected_components(Graph.from_dict(edge_dict))
```

Comment: Ooops. Thank you, that's exactly the problem. I tried with some more test cases. Also the algorithm is ambiguous and confusing (at least to me) that's why I wanted to have this implementation to check I understood it. Thank you again.

Comment: Can you explain why we need 'elif w in stack' instead of just updating 'lowlinks[v] = min(lowlinks[v], indices[w])' if w has already been visited?

Comment: @MinhPham, it's been a while since I carefully thought about this algorithm, but I know that `elif w in stack` is not the same condition as "if w has already been visited". Sometimes, `w` has been visited but is not in the stack, because it has been removed from the stack and placed in the list of connected components. I _think_ this corresponds to situations in which the `v-w` edge connects two components in one direction (from v in one component to w in the other), but there is no connection in the other direction, so the two components are not strongly connected to each other.

Comment: @JonasGröger, glad you created that! Do note that user contributions to Stack Overflow are under a [creative commons license with attribution required](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/06/attribution-required/). It would be great if you could add attribution to that gist. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I modified senderle's answer for Python 3.6+ and added type hints and comments so that it made more sense to me.

```py
from itertools import chain
from collections import defaultdict
from typing import Iterable, DefaultDict, List, Dict, Generic, TypeVar, Tuple, Set

T = TypeVar('T')  # label for a vertex

class Graph(Generic[T]):
    def __init__(self, edges: Iterable[Tuple[T, T]], vertices: Iterable[T] = ()):
        edges = [list(x) for x in edges]
        self.edges = edges
        self.vertices: Set[T] = set(chain(*edges)).union(vertices)
        self.adj_list: DefaultDict[T, List[T]] = defaultdict(list)  # i.e., neighbors of a given node
        for head, tail in self.edges:
            self.adj_list[head].append(tail)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, edge_dict: Dict[T, Iterable[T]]):
        return cls((k, v) for k, vs in edge_dict.items() for v in vs)

def strongly_connected_components(graph: Graph[T]) -> List[List[T]]:
    idx = 0  # index to be assigned to the next node
    node_idxs: Dict[T, int] = {}  # index of a visited node
    lowlink: Dict[T, int] = {}  # low-link number is the lowest node number (index) reachable by the node that is in the same connected component – its own number, or the low-link number of a previous unvisited neighbor, or the node number of a visited neighbor in the stack
    stack: List[T] = []
    connected_components: List[List[T]] = []

    def visit(head: T) -> None:
        nonlocal idx
        lowlink[head] = node_idxs[head] = idx
        idx += 1
        stack.append(head)

        for neighbor in graph.adj_list[head]:
            if neighbor not in node_idxs:  # i.e., not visited
                visit(neighbor)
                lowlink[head] = min(lowlink[head], lowlink[neighbor])
            elif node_idxs[neighbor] < node_idxs[head]:
                if neighbor in stack:
                    lowlink[head] = min(lowlink[head], node_idxs[neighbor])

        if lowlink[head] == node_idxs[head]:
            component: List[T] = []
            while stack and node_idxs[stack[-1]] >= node_idxs[head]:
                component.append(stack.pop())
            connected_components.append(component)

    for v in graph.vertices:
        if v not in node_idxs:
            visit(v)
    return connected_components

if __name__ == '__main__':
    edges = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'),
                ('E', 'A'), ('A', 'E'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'E'),
                ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'B'), ('E', 'F')]
    print(strongly_connected_components(Graph(edges)))  # [['F', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A', 'E']]
    edge_dict = {'a':['b', 'c', 'd'],
                    'b':['c', 'a'],
                    'c':['d', 'e'],
                    'd':['e'],
                    'e':['c']}
    print(strongly_connected_components(Graph.from_dict(edge_dict)))  # [['e', 'd', 'c'], ['b', 'a']]
```