# Graph connections in python

Tags: python, graph, connection

I'm not very familiar with the graph theory, but I'll try to explain my problem.
I have a dictionnary like this:

```
{67: [68, 332],
 68: [67],
 265: [266],
 266: [265],
 332: [67, 333],
 333: [332, 334],
 334: [333, 335],
 335: [334, 336],
 336: [335]}
```

The keys of this dict are nodes, and the values are edges of the graph. 
How can we find the connected groups in this graph? 
[there are two groups - 265->266 and 67->...->366]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your graph is undirected, meaning that, for any two nodes A and B, if there is an edge from A to B then there is an edge from B to A.  To find the connected components of a graph, you can simply use a [depth-first search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search).  Start at any node and follow edges until you can't reach any more nodes without hitting duplicates.  This is the first connected component.  Then start at any node you haven't touched yet and repeat.  You're done when you've reached all the nodes in the graph.

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're talking about [Tarjan's strongly connected components algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarjan's_strongly_connected_components_algorithm).

Here's a Python implementation that I *think* is correct. You'll have to convert the dictionary to a list of edges, as in `[('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'A'), ('A', 'E'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'E'), ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'B'), ('E', 'F')]`:

```
import itertools

def strong_connect(vertex):
    global edges, indices, lowlinks, connected_components, index, stack
    indices[vertex] = index
    lowlinks[vertex] = index
    index += 1
    stack.append(vertex)

    for v, w in (e for e in edges if e[0] == vertex):
        if indices[w] < 0:
            strong_connect(w)
            lowlinks[v] = min(lowlinks[v], lowlinks[w])
        elif w in stack:
            lowlinks[v] = min(lowlinks[v], indices[w])

    if indices[vertex] == lowlinks[vertex]:
        connected_components.append([])
        while stack[-1] != vertex:
            connected_components[-1].append(stack.pop())
        connected_components[-1].append(stack.pop())

edges = [('A', 'B'), ('B', 'C'), ('C', 'D'), ('D', 'E'), ('E', 'A'), ('A', 'E'), ('C', 'A'), ('C', 'E'), ('D', 'F'), ('F', 'B'), ('E', 'F')]
vertices = set(v for v in itertools.chain(*edges))
indices = dict((v, -1) for v in vertices)
lowlinks = indices.copy()
connected_components = []

index = 0
stack = []
for v in vertices:
    if indices[v] < 0:
        strong_connect(v)

print(connected_components)
```

It's from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6575058/577088).

Comment: tarjan is an overkill. the graph seems to be undirected. for every (u,v) in E, (v,u) is also in E. Also, for directed graph, connected and strongly connected are different things.

Comment: True; I didn't bother looking at the graph very carefully, and since the OP said he wasn't familiar, I assumed he or she meant "strongly connected." Still, this is a workable general-case solution, so I'll leave this here for the sake of completeness.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to be doing a lot of graph stuff and don't want the overhead of using [Sage](http://www.sagemath.org) I'd simply install [networkx](http://networkx.lanl.gov/):

```
>>> import networkx as nx
>>> 
>>> nodes_and_edges = {67: [68, 332], 68: [67], 265: [266],
...                    266: [265], 332: [67, 333],  333: [332, 334],
...                    334: [333, 335], 335: [334, 336],  336: [335]}
>>> 
>>> G = nx.Graph(nodes_and_edges)
>>> G
<networkx.classes.graph.Graph object at 0x11ac510>
>>> nx.connected_components(G)
[[67, 68, 332, 333, 334, 335, 336], [265, 266]]
```

Comment: Thanks, I know about networkx, but I wouldn't like to use a whole external lib for a single action...